# How to load all variations and its id by using product_id programmatically using Drupal Commerce-2.x?

Tags: drupal-8, drupal-commerce

How to load the variations_id from product_id on form alter in Drupal commerce-2.x?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need first to load `Product variation entity`, You need to get `Product variation ids from loaded product` and then extract SKU, Price, Currency Code and etc.

```
$parameter = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('commerce_product');
$product = \Drupal\commerce_product\Entity\Product::load((int)$parameter->id());

/*Load Product Variations*/
$entity_manager = \Drupal::entityManager();
$product_variation = $entity_manager->getStorage('commerce_product_variation')->load((int)$product->getVariationIds()[0]);
$price_number = $product_variation->get('price')->getValue()[0]['number'];
$price_currency = $product_variation->get('price')->getValue()[0]['currency_code'];
```

Comment: `\Drupal::entityManager()` is deprecated.  Use `\Drupal::entityTypeManager()` instead.  https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3AentityManager/8.2.x